# Copy first row of dataframe to empty dataframe with same columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes. One contains several rows/columns of information, and the other contains zero information but has the same column headers, e.g.:

**df**

```
    col1   col2
     A       B
     G       F
```

**df1**

```
    col1   col2
```

I simply want to copy the first row of the populated dataframe and append it to the empty dataframe.

```
    df1.loc[0] = df.loc[0]
```

this gives me the following error: `valueError: cannot set a row with mismatched columns.`

I have verified a million times that the columns are indeed the same, is there something else that could be causing this error?

Comment: work on my side

Comment: `loc` or `iloc`?

Comment: Can you share here `df.columns` and `df1.columns`?

Comment: `df1.loc[len(df1)] = df.iloc[0, :]`

Comment: @SergeBallesta `FROM, TO, fromNum, fromName, toNum, toName, TO1, FROM1` I have copy and pasted many times they are 100% the same.

Comment: The solution posted by @rafaelc works

Comment: I suggest using append: `df1 = df1.append(df.iloc[0], ignore_index=True)`